# loading animation for ListView/ListBox/GridView - WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a Listview in my application for which i need to bind more than 1000 items. while fetching the data i am able to display a message to the user saying "fetching items....". once fetching the data completes "fetching items.." message got disappeared and after some time my data is being displayed in listview.

basically message is disappearing during databinding time. so my question is, how can i display "fetching items..." message until my listview completes binding of all the items ?

can anyone please suggest me some ideas on how to implement this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting your ListView and the TextBlock in a Grid. And switch between them using the visibility. Use a Task to fetch your Items and then show your ListView when the Task is finished.

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="yourText" Visibility="{Binding TextBlockVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding yourItems}" Visibility="{Binding ListViewVisibility}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

and your ViewModel:

```
        private Visibility _textBlockVisibility;

        public Visibility TextBlockVisibility
        {
            get { return _textBlockVisibility; }
            set
            {
                _textBlockVisibility = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Visibility _listViewVisibility;

        public Visibility ListViewVisibility
        {
            get { return _listViewVisibility; }
            set
            {
                _listViewVisibility = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private async void StartFetchItems()
        {
            ShowTextBlock();
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(FetchItemsAsync).ContinueWith(task2=>ShowListView());
        }

        private async Task FetchItemsAsync()
        {
           ....fetchyourItems 
        }

        private void ShowTextBlock()
        {
            TextBlockVisibility=Visibility.Visible;
            ListViewVisibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void ShowListView()
        {
            ListViewVisibility=Visibility.Visible;
            TextBlockVisibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```